# STM32F4 GPIO LED With External Interrupt

Tags: c, microcontroller, gpio, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I am trying to use an external button connect to PA1 to trigger an external interrupt in order to switch on a LED(on PD12). I have tried using a variable declared in stm32f4xx_it.c and setting it = 1 inside the EXTI1_IRQHandler and also tried using the GPIO Callback function. However, it seems that the Pin is detected as a high continuously even if the button is not pressed.

**Expected Result: Button Not Pressed>>LED OFF>>Button Pressed>>LED On**

**Practical Result: Button Not Pressed>>LED ON>>Button Pressed>>LED On**

I do not know why this is happening, I tried testing to see if maybe I had wired my button on my breadboard wrong, but it works just fine if I connect one side to +5v and add a resistor and LED in series, LED goes on when button is pressed and off when not pressed.

EDIT: The code works on a new project using the discovery board's inbuilt button and LED, however when trying to use my own external button the LED switches on as soon as I connect a wire to the pin on the board, without it even being connected on the other side to the breadboard, so somehow it is getting told that the pin is high?

I will attach some code below:

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{


  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
  UNUSED(GPIO_Pin);
  /* NOTE: This function Should not be modified, when the callback is needed,
           the HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback could be implemented in the user file
   */
  if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_1)
    {
        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1))
        {
    
        buttonpressed=1;
        }

    }

}
```

```
  while (1)
  {

       if(buttonpressed==1){
         
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
         
      }
      buttonpressed=0;

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Comment: Do not have it implemented currently, but I would just do something like 

`if(!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1)))
        {
    
        buttonpressed=0;
        }`

and then in my while loop writepin to reset, I had this code in previously, but it did not make a difference, the LED turns on without me pressing the button

Comment: Please post also RCC and interrupt setup code. Hard to say anything without that.
Is it STM32F4Discovery evaluation board?

Comment: @alagner I think I figured it out, I needed to set a pull up resistor for the EXTI Interrupt